Set different from email address for each record type
I want to set different from email addresses for each record type. I saw many articles to use pre defined field values and tried to create a formula in Predefined Field Values for Email action like below but this is also not working.
CASE(Case.RecordType.DeveloperName,
"record_type_a", "customerservice@company.com",
"record_type_b", "csreply@company.com",
"csreply2@company.com")
